# How to parse a custom XML-style error code response from a website

Tags: java, xml, rest, xml-parsing

I'm developing a program that queries and prints out open data from the local transit authority, which is returned in the form of an XML response.

Normally, when there are buses scheduled to run in the next few hours (and in other typical situations), the XML response generated by the page is handled correctly by the `java.net.URLConnection.getInputStream()` function, and I am able to print the individual results afterwards.

The problem is when the buses are NOT running, or when some other problem with my queries develops after it is sent to the transit authority's web server. When the authority developed their service, they came up with their own unique error response codes, which are also sent as XMLs. For example, one of these error messages might look like this:

```
<Error xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Code>3005</Code>
<Message>Sorry, no stop estimates found for given values.</Message>
</Error>
```

(This code and similar is all that I receive from the transit authority in such situations.)

However, it appears that `URLConnection.getInputStream()` and some of its siblings are unable to interpret this custom code as a "valid" response that I can handle and print out as an error message. Instead, they give me a more generic `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` error. This problem cascades into my program which then prints out a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` error pointing to the offending input stream.

My question is therefore two-fold:

**1. Is there a way to retrieve, parse, and print a custom XML-formatted error code sent by a web service using the plugins that are available in Java?**

**2. If the above is not possible, what other tools should I use or develop to handle such custom codes as described?**

Comment: I hope this doesn't sound rude, but how well do you understand HTTP and REST? It seems likely to me that the server is actually returning 404 (in a correct RESTful manner) and adding some XML to the response body by way of explanation.

Comment: Admittedly, I don't have too much knowledge on either. I frankly thought the HTML server response and the custom XML response were separate, e.g. the HTML response would still be valid but the XML response is the one giving the error. In any case that leaves open the question of getting the error code out when the getInputStream() and related functions refuse to even take a look inside a HTTP 404 response. (goes to take a look again)

Comment: *HTTP*, not HTML. The HTTP response codes go in HTTP *headers* and the XML response goes in the HTTP *response body*.

Answer (score 0):

`URLConnection` isn't up to the job of REST, in my opinion, and if you're using `getInputStream`, I'm almost certain you're not handling character encoding correctly.

Check out Spring's [RestTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-resttemplate) - it's really easy to use (just as easy as `URLConnection`), powerful and flexible. You will need to change the `ResponseErrorHandler`, because the default one will throw an exception on 404, but it looks like you want it to carry on and parse the XML in the response.